# Superimpose Density plot for population and sampling distribution

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Sampling of population has been done 500 times with sample size 100. How to obtain density plot for population and sampling distribution of sample means. Also how to superimpose them when the x and y axis intervals are different ? This needs to be done in R.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: Thanks for responding @ Robert

Comment: This is what I have tried so far :

Comment: #Kernel density plot for Volume(Population) and SampleMeans
d <- density(Volume)
plot(d, main="Kernel Density of Volume")
polygon(d, col="red", border="blue") 

s <- density(sampleMeans)
plot(s, main="Kernel Density of Sample Means")
polygon(s, col="yellow", border="black")

Comment: I am getting the density plot for Volume(population) with Bandwidth 2251 and for Sample means the bandwidth is 280. How do I superimpose these plots ?

Comment: Please put your code in your question, i.e.edit your question!